# Is it safe to squash commits that include a merge commit

Tags: git, git-merge, git-squash

Can I safely squash commits where one of them is a merge commit? My commit history looks like this:

[image]

I'm wondering if there will be problems or conflicts when trying to merge this squashed branch into master. I haven't pushed my branch yet so it shouldn't affect other people's git history.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging-with-squash?view=vsts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there will be problems or conflicts when trying to merge this squashed branch into master.

That question is impossible to answer from here. There will or there won't. But *whether* there will be "problems or conflicts when trying to merge this branch into master" has *nothing* to do with whether the branch is squashed or not. It depends on what's been going on in `master` while you were out, as it were.

Comment: Yeah, conflicts indeed are unrelated - my bad. I was just wondering if merge commits should stay in the git history or they are safe to be squashed like any other commit. So I guess they can be safely squashed?

Comment: Squashing is just a way of reducing the commit history. Personally I think squashing is good and I do it all the time. I'm not sure what "safely" means here (since you are not attempting to rewrite the history already present in another repo — _that_ would be bad).